# Can I connect an NVIDIA GPU to my Lenovo laptop?

Tags: usb, gpu, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo T430 laptop with an Intel i7 processor, 16GB RAM, and 300GB SSD.

It doesn't have a Thunderbolt port.

Can I connect an NVIDIA GPU to my Lenovo laptop and use it for CUDA programming?

If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [service manual](https://thinkpads.com/support/hmm/hmm_pdf/t430_t430i_hmm_en_0b48304_03.pdf) - it looks a *lot* like your PC has an express card slot - which is essentially a PCIe breakout. There's breakout boxes for GPUs - the 'famous' one's called the "exp gdc beast" - which while typically meant for mini PCIe and M.2 have express card variants.

Apparently [folks have done this for gaming](https://www.reddit.com/r/thinkpad/comments/5ljysr/thinkpad_t430_expresscard_egpu/) and while I can't comment on the 'exact' setup to run your GPU with cuda - an express card based breakout would be the 'smart' option here. It is entirely reversible and wouldn't need you to open up your PC every time, and the GPU setup would be mostly self contained and pretty low cost.